# apiconnect: Create API for geoJSON data

Tags: swagger, loopbackjs, apiconnect

Can someone explain how to create an API with APIC toolkit?

I would like to use this API to work with a Cloudant DB on IBM Bluemix or a local CouchDB to create, read and update of the geoJSON data.

Below is an easy example of typical data to store name and coordinates of point of interests.

```
[{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Nice Place 1"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [16.45961, 48.23896]
    } 
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Nice Place 2"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [16.34561, 49.89612]
    }
}]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the loopback documentation on geopoint support ?http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#geopoint

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, I don't see how to model that data model in the toolkit. And beside that, it only addresses data points. geoJSON handles more.

Comment: There is apic loopback where you can create different loopback projects, They provide some basic template, in there you should be able to create your model and properties. but you may need to do some implementation /mapping yourself. Unsure if they support all the datatypes/method you need.

Answer (score 1):

LoopBack supports GeoPoint (i.e. Point in GeoJSON) datatype.
Considering your typical example, let's say you have a model named: Feature, then to use GeoPoint, your `Feature.json` should look like:

```
{
  "name": "Feature",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "geopoint"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Now, this Feature model, having PersistedModel as base, will have common CRUD methods exposed as REST endpoints and you can store data, for example, using CURL:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{
  \"name\": \"Nice Place 1\",
  \"geometry\": {
    \"lat\": 16.20,
    \"lng\": 48.23
  }
}" "http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/Features"
```

Hope that helps with creating an API that supports GeoPoint.

Re: Cloudant db, I am not sure if it supports geo-spatial data out of the box, however there seems support for it: https://cloudant.com/product/cloudant-features/geospatial/

Comment: Yes, I had tried that geopoint type, but the geoJSON structure is a bit different (at least from my point of view).
It's like:

Comment: Ups:

Yes, I had tried that geopoint type, but the geoJSON structure is a bit different (at least from my point of view). It's like:
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [16.45961, 48.23896]
    }

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the model above with a loopback app(using cloudant as ds) and it's explorer:

Create with sample data:

`{
  "name": "string",
  "geometry": {
    "lat": 12,
    "lng": 13
  }
}`

And get it from GET/ myGeoModels successfully:

`[
  {
    "name": "string",
    "geometry": {
      "lat": 12,
      "lng": 13
    },
    "id": "f08301abe833ad427c9c61ffd30df8ef"
  }
]`

APIC should have same behaviour of loopback.